# How to save [NSString characterAtIndex:] to MutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

Im having a lot of problems with saving data from one format to another.
I have `NSString` that is like "BC01234" and i want to save numbers "1", "2" "3" and "4" separatelly in `NSMuttableArray` that already exists. I would like to use it later as numbers.
How to do it?

I was trying something like:

```
self.poziomGrzania[0] = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[dataString characterAtIndex:3]];
```

but it doesn't work.

How should I do that?

Comment: Define "don't work". In what way? Be specific.

Comment: the problem is that I have no idea whats wrong. Im working on an application that gets this string from NSData which is from one of the Characteristics form BLE Device. When i DONT use this part of code, app looks good, it comunicate both ways with the device. But when im trying to use this NSString to get few INTs from and show it on the screen everything starts to crash. Is it a common problem with casting from NSString to NSMutableAray, or should I look somewhere totaly else?

Comment: Update your question with details about the crash.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things are wrong by implication in the code:  if you're adding to an empty array, then (1) that the array shouldn't be addressed by index, and (2) the calculation converting a character to a number is off by the value of '0'.  So...

```
NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy];
NSString *digits = [@"BC01234" substringFromIndex:2];

for( int i=0 ;i<digits.length; ++i) {
    [array addObject:@([digits characterAtIndex:i] - '0')];
}
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Logs: <__NSArrayM 0xblahblah> (
0,
1,
2,
3,
4
)

**EDIT** - or, if the array is already initialized:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @0, @0, @0, @0, nil];
NSString *digits = [string substringFromIndex:2];

for( int i=0 ;i<digits.length; ++i) {
    array[i] = @([digits characterAtIndex:i] - '0');
}
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Comment: thanks! but the NSMutableArray that Im trying to add is not empty.
Its initialised like this at the beginign:
self.poziomGrzania = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @0, @0, @0, @0, nil];

Comment: could you explain me this part please?
    array[i] = @([digits characterAtIndex:i] - '0');
I don't get what menas @() and why im substracting(?) '0'?

Comment: Sure.  That minus expression measures the distance between two ascii values.  The value of the character extracted from the string minus the ascii value of the first digit, '0'.  This works because the digits appear consecutively in ascii (starting at '0').  See here http://www.asciitable.com